# How can antibodies induce a demigod transformation?

Tags: biology, technology, genetics

The Greek gods were sufficiently advanced aliens with access to powerful technology. In the begining of our worlds formation, Zeus created mankind from his own flesh. These mortals were made in their god's image, as sons and daughters of the gods. However, Zeus had a bad habit of "spreading his Royal oats" a little too often. This led to a trail of children across the planet.

The children of Zeus number in the hundreds. However, the vast majority of them are generic mortal humans with no special properties to them. Some children are chosen as babies by a goddess, who takes an interest in them. She nurses the child for six months, after which they complete their transformation into a full demigod.

Breast milk contains antibodies that help your baby fight off viruses and bacteria, as well as fend off certain diseases. How can this affect a child's development and lead to a demigods transformation?

Comment: Do you really want it to be a genetic transformation? Antibodies may only be helpful in unlocking of the genetic potential already there.

Comment: A person who live through smallpox is a demigod already. You don't have brain cortex inflamation, muscles inflamation, your brain is not boiled during fever. You could say that there is some illness that damage "god" part of brain. It don't affect regular humans as they don't have it but in demigods it make them unable to unlock abilites.

Answer (score 3):

- The gods were immortal because they consumed ambrosia. It's a theme present in many world religions. So if this goddess regularly consumes ambrosia, it gets passed on to these children. Only getting a tiny dose may trigger the alien genes dependent on this substance to activate. For tissues which aren't constantly recycled by the body or that grow a lot after birth (think brain, eyes) a one-time exposure to this cofactor may be enough to give them permanent abilities (like psychic powers, access to mentally influenced hyperspace states, etc.) The effects could be developmental, so getting ambrosia as an adult would have very different effects. Demigods wouldn't be immortal, but would have similar (reduced?) powers to the gods.
- If it has to be by antibodies, then hypothesize that the Earthly environment has some teratogenic properties that don't harm humans, but that the gods are inoculated to. By getting these kids past the damaging developmental stages they have the alien parts they need to access godly powers